# #Error1064 sql syntax DECLARE and CURSOR FOR SELECT

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

I keep getting this error : 
*"ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY processdate DESC) rwn,  s.serno
           FROM ord_success s WHERE ga' at line 5"*

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE move_sucess_order(p_gwserno DOUBLE, p_mindate DOUBLE, p_keepsize DOUBLE)
BEGIN
DECLARE NOT_FOUND INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET NOT_FOUND = 1;
   DECLARE rec CURSOR FOR SELECT serno FROM ( SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY processdate DESC) rwn,  s.serno
       FROM ord_success s WHERE gatewayserno = p_gwserno AND processdate < p_mindate
       ) t WHERE rwn > p_keepsize; OPEN rec;
 FETCH rec INTO;
 WHILE NOT_FOUND=0
 DO
 INSERT INTO ord_success_arc
    SELECT serno, gatewayserno, targetserno, meterpointserno, mastermessagetype,
         messagetype, rawcontent, createdate, createuser, createtransactionid, requesttype, processtype,
         lastexecutorendpoint, orderstatus, bidirectedserno, externalherefno, processtarget, isasync, processdate,
         lpstartdate, lpenddate, updatedate, updateuser, updatetransactionid, recordstatus, externalsdmsource, externalsdmserno
     FROM ord_success WHERE serno = rec.serno;
     DELETE FROM ord_success WHERE serno = rec.serno;

    FETCH  INTO;
    END WHILE;
    CLOSE ;
```

I am kind of novice on mysql. I checked mysql manual deeply. But I couldn't figure how I can solve this problem. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: I don't see an end to match the begin, fetch syntax is incorrect, you are not testing for a not found in while loop, you may not be setting delimiters.

Comment: The version is 5.7.12 .

Comment: Row_number is not available until version 8 have a look for mysql rownumber simulation

Comment: I will check, thanks for the info.